# How to solve authentication error when accessing google pay api for passes?

Tags: php, google-pay

I've been following the steps [here](https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/guides/basic-setup/get-access-to-rest-api) and [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client) to try to use a service account key file to access the Google pay api and insert a LoyaltyClass. The Google Pay library suggests using version 1.1.1 of the Google api client library, which is what I've done here:

```php
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/wallet_object.issuer');
$client->setApplicationName("Test");
$client->setDeveloperKey("My service account key");
$test_class = new LoyaltyClass;
$service = new Google_Service_Walletobjects($client);
$wallet_object = $test_class->create_wallet_class();
$service->loyaltyclass->insert($wallet_object);
```

And I get this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Google_Service_Exception: Error calling POST https://www.googleapis.com/walletobjects/v1/loyaltyClass?key=2ee78c76d17cabcdce22c4e89af27ab73ad694a4: (401) Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project. in /var/www/html/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Http/REST.php:76
```

The cloud api console logs that I've reached the api with the correct service account, but doesn't log any requests. The link they suggest directs me to prompt a user to login, but I want to access this api without input from a user, just my service account. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

What are you supplying to `setDeveloperKey`?

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/guides/basic-setup/get-access-to-rest-api#obtain-library) uses `setAuthConfigFile` instead of `setDeveloperKey`:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('Wallet Objects App');
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/wallet_object.issuer'));
$client->setAuthConfigFile('/example/path/to/privatekey.json');
```

There's a [GitHub sample project](https://github.com/google-pay/passes-rest-samples/blob/33e8a86049d1f854eca4781ea0e9b48af0010231/php/RestMethods.php#L26-L35) that initializes the `Google_Client` class which uses the following code:

```php
$this->client = new Google_Client();

// do OAuth2.0 via service account file.
// See https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts#authorizingrequests
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=' . SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE); // for Google_Client() initialization for server-to-server
$this->client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
// Set application name.
$this->client->setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME);
// Set Api scopes.
$this->client->setScopes(array(SCOPES));
```

`SEVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE` is defined in [`Config.php`](https://github.com/google-pay/passes-rest-samples/blob/33e8a86049d1f854eca4781ea0e9b48af0010231/php/Config.php#L30).

If you'd like a step by step tutorial for integrating with the Passes API, there's a codelab that you can follow: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/passes-loyaltyapi

It's written for NodeJS, but most of the concepts should still apply to PHP.

EDIT: Updated to refer to `setAuthConfigFile` from the Google Pay developer site.

EDIT: Updated to include PHP sample code from GitHub

Comment: Hey, I've tried using setAuthConfig instead, and I'm still getting an authorization error. When I look at the credentials screen in the api console, I can click a service account and go to the key tab, and it shows me the key strings associated with that account. When I tried using setAuthConfig, I used the credential that was automatically downloaded when I created a new key for my service account. Is there another credential I should be using? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Are you able to confirm that `setAuthConfig` is set to the file that you downloaded? And that the file that you downloaded looks similar to the JSON sample that I posted above? Were you able to look through the codelab to see if there is anything else missing? For example [granting access to the service account](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/passes-loyaltyapi#2)?

Comment: Also, are you able to confirm that it's the same authorization error? Is it still a `401` or is it a `403`?